# static size array of different struct's

Tags: c++, struct, shared-memory

I have an application that consists of multiple tasks that share common data using shared memory. Up to now the data in shared memory look like that:

```
struct Store = {
    int id;
    Array<Module, 5> modules;
};
```

where `Module` is defined as

```
struct Module = {
    uint32_t a;
    char b[64];
    Array<Component, 10> components;
};
```

This `Store` structure has a fixed size an can be easily used within shared memory.

But now I have to support other Modules, lets say `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`. Within the *normal* C++ context I would model these as:

```
struct ModuleBase {
    // common informations
};
struct ModuleA : public ModuleBase {
    // ...
};
struct ModuleB : public ModuleBase {
    // ...
};
```

and replace `Module` by `Module*` in the `Store`.

But within the **shared memory** this is not so easy. 
Accessing data in shared memory is easy for fix structures that's why a compile time array is used. I would like to have this property with my different module's.

### Idea 1

```
union Module {
    ModuleType type;
    ModuleA moduleA;
    ModuleB moduleB;
};
```

The problem is that my `Module` classes have constructors and that is not allowed inside the `union`. Access is easy using the `type` and then `Module.moduleX` 
**fix**: remove need of constructors

### Idea 2

Using a template that evaluates the maximum size of given classes, e.g.

```
const size_t max_module_size = MaxTMP<ModuleA, ModuleB>::value;
```

This is the size of the buffer I need to store the modules:

```
char ModuleBuffer[max_module_size];
```

(maybe the `ModuleBuffer` has to be encapsulated in a struct, for usage with `Array`)

Access is tricky, the content of `ModuleBuffer` has to be casted to `ModuleBase` and according to the `type` to `ModuleX`. That for I think I need some `reinterpret_cast`. And I also need to cast the 'ModuleX' in some way to put into the `ModuleBuffer`.

## Question

I don't like both ideas but I cannot imagine another way to handle this problem. Do you have any comments or - even better - solutions?

Comment: How about a `boost::variant<ModuleA, ModuleB>`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't know how type info is stored and could be used inside shared memory. Anyone any experience??

Comment: Check the documentation. If all your types have non-throwing constructors, everything is stored in one shared piece of automatic memory, so it should work nicely in your shared memory scenario.

Comment: Look at boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory. They have a kind of smart pointer that is usable within a shared memory segment.

Comment: @KerrekSB Where can I find the information about non-throwing constructors and automatic memory? So I have to check if `boost::variant` works across process boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, you are between a rock and a hard place.

I would give a try to `boost::variant`, because of the facilities it comes with, otherwise it's not too difficult to recreate a similar thing, but it is long...

---

On top of size, you also need to take care about alignment. It will help to use C++11 here, although it is possible to write this in C++03 with a couple libraries/extensions.

Note that a `union` is not anything so special, and you can easily implement your own, in a way, and like `boost::variant` make it "tagged".

A couple helpers will help nicely:

```
/// Size and Alignment utilties
constexpr size_t max(size_t t) { return t; }

template <typename... U>
constexpr size_t max(size_t l, size_t r, U... tail) {
    return l > max(r, tail...) ? l : max(r, tail...);
}

template <typename... T>
struct size { static size_t const value = max(sizeof(T)...); };

template <typename... T>
struct alignment { static size_t const value = max(alignof(T)...); };


/// Position of a type in the list
template <typename...> struct position;

template <typename T>
struct position<T> {
    static size_t const value = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct position<T, Head, Tail...> {
    static size_t const value =
        std::is_same<T, Head>::value ? 0 : 1 + position<T, Tail...>::value;
};


/// Type at a given position
template <size_t, typename...> struct at;

template <size_t N, typename T, typename... Tail>
struct at<N, T, Tail...> { typedef typename at<N-1, Tail..>::type type; };

template <typename T, typename... Tail>
struct at<0, T, Tail...> { typedef T type; };
```

Now the true fun starts: how to apply a function in a typesafe manner with a type that may change at runtime :x ?

```
/// Function application
template <typename...> struct Apply;

template <typename H, typename... Tail>
struct Apply<H, Tail...> {
    // Mutable
    template <typename Func>
    static void Do(Func& f, void* storage, size_t tag) {
         if (tag == 0) { f(*reinterpret_cast<H*>(storage)); }
         else { Apply<Tail...>::Do(f, storage, tag-1); }
    }
    template <typename Func>
    static void Do(Func const& f, void* storage, size_t tag) {
         if (tag == 0) { f(*reinterpret_cast<H*>(storage)); }
         else { Apply<Tail...>::Do(f, storage, tag-1); }
    }

    // Const
    template <typename Func>
    static void Do(Func& f, void const* storage, size_t tag) {
         if (tag == 0) { f(*reinterpret_cast<H const*>(storage)); }
         else { Apply<Tail...>::Do(f, storage, tag-1); }
    }
    template <typename Func>
    static void Do(Func const& f, void const* storage, size_t tag) {
         if (tag == 0) { f(*reinterpret_cast<H const*>(storage)); }
         else { Apply<Tail...>::Do(f, storage, tag-1); }
    }
}; // struct Apply

/// We need recursion to end quietly even though `tag` is a runtime argument
/// we place the precondition that `tag` should be a valid index in the type
/// list so this should never be reached.
template <>
struct Apply<> {
    template <typename... T>
    static void Do(T...&&) { abort(); }
}; // struct Apply
```

Now we can use this to dynamically dispatch in a type safe manner.

```
/// Variant itself
template <typename... List>
class Variant {
public:
    /// Constructor & co
    Variant() {
        typedef typename at<0, List...>::type First;
        new (&_storage) First();
    }

    Variant(Variant const& other) {
        this->initialize(other);
    }

    Variant& operator=(Variant const& other) {
        this->destroy();
        this->initialize(other);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Variant() { this->destroy(); }

    /// Conversions
    template <typename T>
    explicit Variant(T const& t) {
        _tag = position<T, List...>::value;
        new (&_storage) T(t);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Variant& operator=(T const& t) {
        _tag = position<T, List...>::value;
        this->destroy();
        new (&_storage) T(t);
        return *this;
    }

    /// Applying a func
    template <typename Func>
    void apply(Func& f) { Apply<List...>::Do(f, &_storage, _tag); }

    template <typename Func>
    void apply(Func& f) const { Apply<List...>::Do(f, &_storage, _tag); }

    template <typename Func>
    void apply(Func const& f) { Apply<List...>::Do(f, &_storage, _tag); }

    template <typename Func>
    void apply(Func const& f) const { Apply<List...>::Do(f, &_storage, _tag); }

private:
    void initialize(Variant const& v) {
        struct {
            template <typename T>
            void operator()(T& t) const { new (_storage) T(t); }
            void* _storage;
        } copier = { &_storage };

        v.apply(copier);
        _tag = v._tag;
    }

    void destroy() {
        struct {
            template <typename T>
            void operator()(T& t) const { t.~T(); }
        } eraser;

        this->apply(eraser);
    }

    std::aligned_storage<size<List...>::value,
                         alignment<List...>::value> _storage;
    size_t _tag;
}; // class Variant
```

Did I say easy ?

Well, there is a subtle issue still: the `operator=` implementations are not exception safe. In your case it should not be an issue, since you do not have dynamic memory allocation in those types.

References:

- [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)

Comment: Huu, I'm happy you didn't say easy :-) I will have a look at `boost::variant`. Thank you!